# Testing for 3 way conditions in C

Tags: c, conditional-statements

How do I test for three way conditions in C?

For example (pseudo format):

```
if n and z and p
 {
   print nzp
 }
else if (n and z) and not p
 {
   print nz
 }

...........
```

Comment: Do you know how to test for 2 way conditions?

Answer (score 4):

```
if (n && z)
{
   if (p)
     print nzp
   else
     print nz
}
```

Comment: I prefer this answer instead of mine because of its better readability

Answer (score 2):

Maybe :

```
if (n && z && p)
{
   print nzp
}
else if ((n && z) && !p)
{
   print nz
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could write:

```
switch ( (n ? 4 : 0) + (z ? 2 : 0) + (p ? 1 : 0) ) {
case 7:
    ...  // all three true
    break;
case 6:
    ...  // n and z true, p false
    break;
...
}
```

But it seems better to just use nested conditions:

```
if (n) {
    if (z) {
        if (p) {
            ...  // all three true
        } else {
            ...  // n and z true, p false
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Being n, z and p conditions which could de evaluated by a regular if statement, than you could write:

```
if (n && z && pp)
{
//your code here
}
else if (n && z && !p)
{
//more code
}
```

Or, if just want to print information about the conditions which are true, instead of analysing each combination you could do three separate if statements:

```
if (n)
    //print n
if (z)
    //print z
if (p)
    //print p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <iso646.h>

int main(void){
    bool n = true;
    bool z = true;
    bool p = true;

redo:
    if(n and z and p){
        printf("nzp\n");
    } else if((n and z) and not p) {
        printf("nz\n");
    }

    if(p){
        p = not p;
        goto redo;
    }

    return 0;

}
```